# Blender Python: cannot delete or access keyframes set previously with a python script

Tags: python, css-animations, blender

I am able to set keyframes using a python script.  The keyframes are added and the animation works correctly.

```
#Sets the value of the mix shader factor at a vaiable keyframe named "start_frame"
mix_colour.inputs[0].default_value = 0
mix_colour.inputs[0].keyframe_insert(data_path = 'default_value', frame= (float (start_frame)))
```

If however, I want to edit these keyframes cannot find a way back to them.  So for example I want to delete all of the keyframe on mix_colour nothing happens and the keyframe persist.

I have tried using variations on:

```
mix_colour.inputs[0].keyframe_delete(data_path='default_value')
```

but nothing I seem to try lets me get back to the keyframes.

I can select them manually and delete them.

any help much appreciated.